# Start Workflow from Display/Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, workflow

Does anyone know the steps for creating a run workflow button on a display/edit form. My workflow has an initiation form as well and ideally that would open from the item display/edit form.

It was talked about in post but Im not sure how to achieve the correct outcome.

[Cannot start workflow from JS in Display Form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177552/cannot-start-workflow-from-js-in-display-form/177690#177690)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Ribbon, Menu and Form Actions in SharePoint Designer. You must go on the list page, in the section Custom Actions and create a new of the correct time. There you will be able to launch a Workflow of your choice.

Hope this helps!